# Font awesome icons won't show

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, visual-web-developer

I am Coding a website and i am incorporating font awesome icons but even though I have added the link-tag at the top of the page it won't show me the icons

This is the link I Added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

This is how I incorporated it

```
<div class="billboard-social-icons">
                <ul class="social-icons-white">
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-behance"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- billboard-social-icons Ends Here -->
```

Comment: Your code is fine, tested it with https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css. The path to your css file is probably incorrect.

Comment: are you using the CDN or locally?

Comment: please add console log of loaded page, - there most probably would be some errors that provided paths are not reachable or smth like that

Comment: You can create a 'kit' on their website which gives you more options than usual

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CDN if you want to use. There might be some issue with the css file you are adding.

```html
<div class="billboard-social-icons">
                <ul class="social-icons-white">
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- billboard-social-icons Ends Here --> 
            
        
          <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/50a7448982.js"></script>
```